# How to prevent back button press from external keyboard (Bluetooth scanner) in React Native Android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using an external Bluetooth Scanner with my React Native Android application. 
 For some reason when the scanner scans the barcode but I have not selected the input box, the external Bluetooth scanner triggers a back button press which I want to prevent. 
 However, the back button press from the on-screen keyboard or from the android navigation bar should work as expected.

I tried 'react-native-keyevent'

```
import KeyEvent from 'react-native-keyevent';

componentDidMount() {
   
    KeyEvent.onKeyDownListener((keyEvent) => {
       return true;
    });
    KeyEvent.onKeyUpListener((keyEvent) => {
      return true;
    });
 }
```

It calls the KeyEvent.onKeyDownListener and KeyEvent.onKeyUpListener on back key press from the external keyboard but `return true;` doesn't prevent them from going back.

I also used

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

 componentDidMount() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => { return true });
  }
```

This successfully prevents the back button press from the external keyboard(Bluetooth scanner) but it also blocks back keypress from the android navigation bar.

I want to distinguish if the back key press was from the external keyboard (Bluetooth scanner) or from an android navigation bar so that I can allow back on the android navigation bar and prevent back on the external keyboard.